# SONY CameraRemoteAPI Android camera detection not working

Tags: android, api, camera, controls, sony

I am trying out the official Sony CameraRemoteAPI and its example application for Android. The sample application however is not finding my A6000 camera on 239.255.255.250:1900 like it is written in their official Developers Guide.

The official documentation says:
"First, you need to enable the remote control function on your camera. The camera will then act as an access point. Then you should connect your phone or tablet to the camera access point. On the phone or tablet, select the camera access point and input the password displayed on the camera or described in the manuals."

I found some suggestions online to start the "Smart Remote Control" app on the camera so the android device can detect it. (This makes sense because it is the one displaying password while waiting for connection.) This did not work for me with the demo application however (but the official "PlayMemories Mobile" app still works).

Can anyone help me how to set my camera (Sony A6000) for the incoming connection?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

On your Android device you need to go into your wi-fi settings (outside of the application) and select the camera's access point as your wi-fi network, and when the device prompts you for the wi-fi password you need to use the password that's specified on the camera label where the SSID is also located. I believe the "PlayMemories Mobile" app automatically detects the camera's wi-fi access point whereas the built-in app requires you to find and connect to it in your device's wi-fi settings. You may have noticed that when you connect to the camera from the "PlayMemories Mobile" app that it tells you that it's disconnected from the camera's connection, that is because I believe the application is switching wi-fi networks for you.

Hope this helps... Also, in case you're wondering, I'm unsure of how to connect the Android device to the internet while simultaneously connected to the Camera's wi-fi access point. Maybe there's a way to be connected to two wi-fi networks simultaneously on your Android device? Or maybe there's a way to have the camera's API be available through another network which is connected to the internet? I don't know, but I'm currently looking for solutions to this.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Only problem is that i have to start the "Smart Remote Control" app on the camera, and that does not support video features. Accessing video features was the main reason I wanted to develop an app to provide advance video features extending the camera's features.

Comment: I see. Yeah it seems like the A6000 is one of the few cameras that support the remote API but not movie recording/mode according to the docs. I was actually working with a DSC-QX10 the other day when I posted my answer. I have since, coincidentally, been using the A6000, and have found that one extra command that is different in order to get the camera to start listening to input over the API is that I need to call the API with 'startRecMode', which the QX10 doesn't need.